# htaccess rewrite proxy mask doesn't always mask path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On a local network, I have some URLs that I want to make easier.  For example:

Actual path:

```
http://localserver/sites/website.com/html
```

Which I want to access with:

```
http://localserver/website
```

I don't want the full path to be shown.

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/website
RewriteRule ^website(.com)?(/.*)?$ /sites/website.com/html$2 [P,L]
```

It works as expected when there's a trailing slash or a file in the request, but if there isn't it redirects to the full path.

These work:

- http://localserver/website/
- http://localserver/website/index.php
- http://localserver/website/about/

These redirect to the real path:

- http://localserver/website
- http://localserver/website/about

What do I need to change to always mask the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running multiple sites on your localhost server, it would suggest doing this: http://drupal.org/node/161975

If that doesn't apply in your case, this post will solve your problem:
[invisible mod_rewrite is not always invisible!? ("www" and "without subdomain")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083514/invisible-mod-rewrite-is-not-always-invisible-www-and-without-subdomain/9084678#9084678)

Comment: This is a local development environment, so that Drupal article [Set up a Windows test server using XAMPP](http://drupal.org/node/161975) does actually apply (sort of... I'm using Linux), but I was hoping to be able to make changes often without resorting to gaining admin access.  The [other Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083514/invisible-mod-rewrite-is-not-always-invisible-www-and-without-subdomain/9084678#9084678) you gave is the solution I was looking for.  `DirectorySlash Off` and a `RedirectRule` for directories is the most effective solution.