# Rewriting www subfolder works except for empty requests (domain root) since apache update

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, url-rewriting

I had some .htaccess lines that worked for transparently rewriting my www subdomain to a www subfolder. Now, since a server update, it doesn't work anymore.
Actually, it does still work, except for root without request (number 1 below), which gives a 404 now. 
What's going on? Doesn't `!^/www` include empty requests?

This is what I want and worked before:

1. http://www.e-motiv.net              -> subfolder: www
   doesn't work anymore
2. http://www.e-motiv.net/anything     -> subfolder: www/anything
3. http://e-motiv.net/www/(anything)   -> don't rewrite

These are my htaccess lines:

```
#### www -> folder /www (not possible via Control Panel)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.e-motiv\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www
RewriteRule ^ /www%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]  #Variant

#check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083514
DirectorySlash Off
#www dir only
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 -d
RewriteRule ^www/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
#other dirs
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
####
```

EDIT: I discoverd if I add R in fourth line, it works again, except that everyone can see it now, which I don't want. I am wondering now if it's not related to the bug said in [Internal URL rewrite no longer working after upgrading Apache to 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023601/internal-url-rewrite-no-longer-working-after-upgrading-apache-to-2-4)
EDIT: Third case rewritten from "http://e-motiv.net/www" to "http://e-motiv.net/www/" as it makes no sense without slash.
EDIT: ALthough there is a workaround below for my case, the best thing to do is update your apache!  My hoster couldn't, so for those who are in the same situation, it's still meaningfull (and instructive).

Comment: Does `/www/` folder also have .htaccess?

Comment: Nope. Also, I discoverd if I add R in fourth line, it works again, except that everyone can see it now, which i don't want. I am wondering if it's not related to the bug said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023601/internal-url-rewrite-no-longer-working-after-upgrading-apache-to-2-4

Comment: Adding the following lines are a workaround to my problem:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.e-motiv\.net$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/index.php [QSA,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule has worked for me in Apache 2.4:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.e-motiv\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ www/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.e-motiv\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!www/).*)$ www/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Exact same problem with those lines. Which apache version do you have?

Comment: I have **Apache/2.4.12**

Comment: In the bug I referenced, they say it's only fixed in 2.4.9. Since you have a higher version, it seems to point to me experiencing that bug after all.

Comment: Hmm, can you test my updated rules on your Apache 2.4.9

Comment: That seems to work better, except: http://e-motiv.net/www. That one shows the html, but not the css, although the css can be found where it should:
http://e-motiv.net/www/css/general.css.
But then again, http://e-motiv.net/www/ (notice the "/") DOES work.

Comment: It is because your page is using css as `<link href="css/general.css"` which is a relative path. Now when you load `http://e-motiv.net/www` it will attempt to load css using `http://e-motiv.net/css/general.css` since there is no trailing slash. We can force a trailing slash after `www` OR just make last rule as `RewriteRule ^((?!www).*)$ www/$1 [L,NC]` and then it should work.

Comment: You should also add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/www/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: You're mistaken on that base tag. Since it has to work with all the variants in my original post it has to be relative (with and without www folder).  Also,  a web developer should not have to set the bas tag for this case.  
You're probably right on that last rule though.  But I am gonna do without the third variant. If peoplee still reach my site with www at the end, I will notice in my stats.  It was a bad idea of mine to keep it running (especially if there is no slash at the end. I will update post too.)

Comment: It's wrong, because it wouldn't work for all cases in my question.   (There is no www folder in www.e-motiv.net :-) ). Anyway, the problem is futile now -> "gonna do without the third variant" (without slash).
P.S. Grats on working around that apache bug. There are a lot of stackoverflow posts with it that you might wanna get some points from. ;-)

Comment: I would sincerely advise them all to upgrade if at all it is possible :)

Comment: Yeah. I know, that's the best advise. I advised my hoster, who's a comrade of mine, too about that, but he won't.  Probably too much work already done in transferring zillion of his customers...